Why does `GeometryReader` return a smaller size during window resize while the view visually retains its size?
I am using GeometryReader in SwiftUI to track the frame of a Color.black background. However, when I resize the window, the size retrieved from GeometryReader (via geo.frame(in: .local)) unexpectedly shrinks, even though the Color.black background visually remains the correct size.
Here’s the code I am using:
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var rect: CGRect = CGRect()

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
      ZStack {
        Color.black
          .onAppear {
            rect = geo.frame(in: .local)
          }
          .onChange(of: geo.frame(in: .local)) { oldValue, newValue in
            rect = newValue
          }

        Color.red.frame(width: rect.width, height: 2.0)
        Color.blue.frame(width: 2.0, height: rect.height)
        Color.green
          .frame(width: 300.0, height: 50.0)
          .offset(y: -100.0)
      }
    }
    .padding(300.0)
  }
}

Why is the size value from the GeometryReader shrinking during a window resize, and how can I ensure it always matches the size of the Color.black background?

This is because the size of the GeometryReader is more flexible than the size of the Color.black. It can change to a size that is smaller than the Color.black. The Color.black is always as large as the ZStack, which is at least as large as the Color.green.
You can see the size of the GeometryReader by adding a .border(.red) to the it. before the padding.
So one way to solve this is just not to consider the cases where the size of the GeometryReader is smaller than the Color.black. It's not very clear what should the view look like when that happens, anyway. You can do this by setting a minimum size:
GeometryReader { geo in
    // ...
}
.frame(minWidth: 300, minHeight: 50)
.padding(300.0)

If you want the Color.black to be resizable to a size smaller than the Color.green, do not put them in the same ZStack. Use an overlay/background to put one on top of/below the other.
GeometryReader { geo in
    Color.black
        .onAppear {
            rect = geo.frame(in: .local)
        }
        .onChange(of: geo.frame(in: .local)) { oldValue, newValue in
            rect = newValue
        }
        .overlay {
            ZStack {
                Color.red.frame(width: rect.width, height: 2.0)
                Color.blue.frame(width: 2.0, height: rect.height)
                Color.green
                    .frame(width: 300.0, height: 50.0)
                    .offset(y: -100.0)
            }
        }
}
.padding(300.0)

Other notes:

Consider using onGeometryChange instead of a GeometryReader:

Color.black
    // .frame(minWidth: 300, minHeight: 50) // you can still add this if you want
    .onGeometryChange(for: CGRect.self) {
        $0.frame(in: .local)
    } action: { newValue in
        rect = newValue
    }
    .overlay {
        ZStack {
            Color.red.frame(width: rect.width, height: 2.0)
            Color.blue.frame(width: 2.0, height: rect.height)
            Color.green
                .frame(width: 300.0, height: 50.0)
                .offset(y: -100.0)
        }
    }
    .padding(300.0)


Colors naturally expand to their container's size, so you don't actually need a GeometryReader here at all. I will assume that this is just a toy example and what you are actually doing does require a GeometryProxy.
frame(in: .local) will almost always return a rect with origin (0, 0). Consider using a CGSize if you just need the size.


EDIT Answer updated based on the assumption that this question concerns macOS only.
A GeometryReader is greedy and will take all the space available. Then, the views inside the GeometryReader are laid out inside this space, with alignment top-leading (that is, aligned to the top-left corner of the GeometryReader).

I am using GeometryReader in SwiftUI to track the frame of a Color.black background

What you are actually tracking is the frame of the GeometryReader in its own coordinate space (because .local is used as coordinate space).
If in fact you want to know the size of the black rectangle then you can use .onGeometryChange to read it instead. Although not apparent from the modifier's name, this also measures the initial size on first show:
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.black
            .onGeometryChange(for: CGRect.self) { geo in
                geo.frame(in: .local)
            } action: { frame in
                // print("frame=\(frame)")
                rect = frame
            }
        Color.red.frame(width: rect.width, height: 2.0)
        Color.blue.frame(width: 2.0, height: rect.height)
        Color.green
            .frame(width: 300.0, height: 50.0)
            .offset(y: -100.0)
    }
    .padding(300.0)
}

The problem with this approach is that the window can only be made larger, not smaller. This is because the size of the ZStack is constrained by the red and blue colors, which are still set to the rect from before.
If you are simply trying to match the size of the red and blue rectangles to the black one, an easier approach is to use an overlay. An overlay automatically adopts the size of the view it is applied to. So you no longer need a state variable to record the size of the black rectangle:
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.black
            .overlay {
                ZStack {
                    Color.red.frame(height: 2.0)
                    Color.blue.frame(width: 2.0)
                }
            }
        Color.green
            .frame(width: 300.0, height: 50.0)
            .offset(y: -100.0)
    }
    .padding(300.0)
}


The question mentions a resizable window, so I’d assume this is about macOS, not iPhones and iPads as you mentioned.

@Sweeper Yes, I think you're right, that just dawned on me too. But the solutions proposed in the answer are valid for macOS too.
